# What is $2b$ in /etc/master.passwd

Tags: freebsd, password

According to [Securing section in FreeBSD Manual](https://docs.freebsd.org/en/books/handbook/security/#security-passwords), the `$2a$` corresponds to blowfish. But In my FreeBSD box I have `$2b$`.

```
xan:$2b$04$F1SclFRRh8c8N6ICwdAb.ud5lfTKhRyL1PuRxvUDsQINlsK8YG9Em:1001:1001::0:0:Xavier J. B. L.:/home/xan:/usr/local/bin/bash
```

What is that? Why not `$2a$`?

Note that I'm sure I have blowfish encryption, because I have `:passwd_format=blf:` in `/etc/login.conf` and I run `# cap_mkdb /etc/login.conf`.

Comment: I confirm it is a duplicate of pointed question although my question is about FreeBSD and not about GNU/Linux (which the pointed question is about)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is also Blowfish, but of a newer version.

You can look at the history of codes and reasons for new versions here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt